# UITableView last row separator is wrong color

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am on iOS 8.
I add a view for the footer to stop empty rows at end of the UITableView with

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewIn viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I have a custom separator colour for the table using

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = NAV_FG_COLOUR;
```

However the last row separator is defaulting back to white.
Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure you have set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` in your `UITableViewCell`. Otherwise there could be double `_UITableViewCellSeparatorView` in your cell. One of those will have wrong color for last cell.
- if `clipsToBounds` is `YES` already then this white color is the background color of `UITableViewCell` itself. Because last cell doesn't have separator at all when footer view is set up for the table. However height of `contentView` of your last cell is still 0.5pt less than height of cell. So that it makes visible background color of the cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

use this to set the separator color

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Sorry, I was using that already, I just put the wrong snippet in the question. But thanks for the answer.